# JFileChooser in a JMenu Issue

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, jmenu

I am having an issue with the JFileChooser in a JMenu. Currently I've got it to set an icon to the background JLabel which works great. But you can only select a file from jumping through folders or using the upper directory button. If I trying using the drop down menu to select a Directory like Desktop for example the focus from the JMenu goes away and so does the JFileChooser, all that is left is the drop down menu just floating there. As soon as you click on any directory the drop down menu disappears as well and does nothing(doesn't select the directory).

Here is my Code so far: **Edited** Changed to test code so you can see for yourself the issue.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class test {
private JFrame frame;

public test() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 686, 462);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mntest = new JMenu("test");
    menuBar.add(mntest);

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    mntest.add(fileChooser);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                test window = new test();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

I've tried messing with the setting for awhile now but can't figure out how to keep focus on the menu while selecting the drop down menu.

Any help would be great. I'm sure it's something simple and stupid but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Normally you use a `JFileChooser#showOpenDialog` or equivalent. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Code has been updated thanks for the tip=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, don't add the `JFileChooser` to the `JMenu`, instead, add a `JMenuItem` which, when triggered, shows the choosers dialog

See [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;

    public Test() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 686, 462);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mntest = new JMenu("test");
        menuBar.add(mntest);
        JMenuItem mi = new JMenuItem("Open...");
        mntest.add(mi);

        mi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                switch (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame)) {
                    case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
                        // Open file...
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test window = new Test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I thought I might have to do it this way I just liked the look and feel of it from the menu but nevermind

Comment: The problem is, once the menu losses focus, it closes :P

Comment: Yea, I was hoping for a way to keep focus on multiple. But This works as well just not as nice looking :P

Comment: I don't know about "nice", but it is expected behavior for a normal user.  A "trick" might be to listen to the activation of the `JMenu` and add the `JFileChooser` to the frames glass pane instead...but it's a "trick" and might require a lot more work then the resulting behavior is worth...

Comment: by "nice" I meant it would look like all the other menu's on my full screen application, sounds like more trouble than its worth, was hoping for a way to keep the menu focused until either a file was opened or the cancel button is pressed. thanks for your help though = )